# What is the way to calculate center possitions from WKT format POLYGON?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, maps

I have a polygon, for exapmle

```
  `POLYGON((
    4977994.67879995 5126870.48124117,
    4977998.08163505 5126894.51511692, 
    4978000.17683601 5126902.67634682, 
    4978001.98260158 5126910.54986973, 
    4978001.64766071 5126910.6200214,
    4978002.08492168 5126914.12175041,
    4977953.43440634 5126927.99302449,
    4977940.83863791 5126869.70314027,
    4977992.37553521 5126855.86154269,
    4977994.67879995 5126870.48124117
    ))`;
```

When OpenLayers renders shape on the appropriate location, I would like to zoom in to that place. What is the way to get corresponding center positions from this WKT POLYGON ?

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import WKT from "ol/format/WKT";
import { OSM, Vector as VectorSource } from "ol/source";
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";

var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

var wkt =
  `POLYGON((
    4977994.67879995 5126870.48124117,
    4977998.08163505 5126894.51511692, 
    4978000.17683601 5126902.67634682, 
    4978001.98260158 5126910.54986973, 
    4978001.64766071 5126910.6200214,
    4978002.08492168 5126914.12175041,
    4977953.43440634 5126927.99302449,
    4977940.83863791 5126869.70314027,
    4977992.37553521 5126855.86154269,
    4977994.67879995 5126870.48124117
    ))`;

var format = new WKT();

var feature = format.readFeature(wkt, {
  dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
  featureProjection: "EPSG:4326"
});

var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    features: [feature]
  })
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [4977968.5506041, 5126889.6132721],
    zoom: 18
  })
});
```

Comment: The center doesn't do much good without the dimensions; since retrieving an extent is a basic capability, and computing the center of an extent is trivial, you ought to be looking for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd want to zoom in on the polygon, simply use `view.fit` . See example on OL website https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html

To calculate the actual centroid of the polygon you could use a library such as [turf js](https://turfjs.org)